# Value attribute in HTML is not showing the expected output

Tags: php, html

```
<form>
    <?php
    $mis = '111503062';
    $db = new DB();
    $query = "SELECT * from Extracurricular where MIS =".$mis;
    $result = $db->run_query($query);
    $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $data1['Activities'];
    echo '<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Extracurricular Activities</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" value='.$data1['Activities'].'></textarea>
    </div>'
    ?>
</form>
```

The echo statement above is working but why value attribute not showing the same data in text-box below.

Comment: textarea does not have value . please check this :
`  echo '<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Extracurricular Activities</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">'.$data1['Activities'].'</textarea>
    </div>'`

Answer (score 2):

Textarea are not using value for setting it's value, instead set it within each `<textarea>` tag :

```
echo '<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Extracurricular Activities</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" >'.$data1['Activities'].'</textarea>
</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` values are in the tag content, not the `value` param.

```
<textarea>The value goes here.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the textarea. The use of Textarean is as follows.

```
<form>
    <?php
    $mis = '111503062';
    $db = new DB();
    $query = "SELECT * from Extracurricular where MIS =".$mis;
    $result = $db->run_query($query);
    $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $data1['Activities'];
    echo '<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Extracurricular Activities</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">'.$data1['Activities'].'</textarea>
    </div>'
    ?>
</form>
```